# Calling an external API from MS Teams chat

Tags: microsoft-teams

Can anyone offer guidance on how to call an external API from within MS Teams chat/posts initiated by an @mention or #hastag?  The service I want to build would use the mention/hastag to call an API and return various types of meta data that would then be added to the chat, post, etc.  Wondering if Flow or Yo Teams is the best way to go.

Comment: You can check the @mention in entities of turnContext activity based on that you can call your external API,

Answer (score 4):

The best approach for this would be to create a bot, which gets a name that can be '@' mentioned (e.g. if you bot is called MyBot, you could mention @MyBot in a Teams channel, and it will get notified). Once it receives the notification, the bot can do anything you need it to do.

If you have development skills available (yourself or someone on your team), have a look at the [Teams Bot development documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots) to get started. If not, [Power Virtual Agents](https://powervirtualagents.microsoft.com/en-us/) could suit your needs (it's like a "drag and drop" bot creator.

Comment: Wow, I never thought of this until I accidentally read this answer. I have a chatbot built on custom OpenAI APIs, but I guess I can simply integrate its custom API and respond wherever it gets called using @MyBot.