# Calling an API from MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I need help regarding how to call an external API **(deployed to MuleSoft Cloudhub)** from MS Teams chat/posts.
I want to interact with cloudhub deployed Mule API to perform operations such as starting, stopping, restarting, and updating mule applications in bulk from the MS Teams chat.

I've seen the following link and my question is exactly similar to this question:
[Calling an external API from MS Teams chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795223/calling-an-external-api-from-ms-teams-chat)

But I need something like **"Slack Slash Commands"** to send request to external APIs. here is a link which contains demo using Slack and I want to achieve same using MS teams:
https://dev.to/vignesh19/slack-bot-for-support-personnel-build-with-api-led-connectivity-7o1

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You said that the question you linked to is the same, so what do you feel is different for your scenario, that the answer there doesn't apply? Please elaborate more on that, so we can try help better.

Comment: There is no MuleSoft, CloudHub nor Mule component in this question. The REST API request is going to be initiated from Microsoft Teams but as far as the details provided in the question state it seems to be a completely generic HTTP request, similar to making the request to any other REST API implementation.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow
In my scenario, I want to hit external API from MS teams without creating any Bot.
Similar to what mentioned in second link which uses "Slash Command" to call external API

Comment: @aled
you're right, it's not specific to Mule/Cloudhub and it could be any external call.
 
I just mentioned Cloudhub to elaborate what I want to achieve. I want to send START/STOP etc command to Mule API which further perform START/STOP operations on Mule apps.

Comment: In simple terms, yes, there is a way to achieve something similar to slash commands, but yes, it require a bot - I'm not sure why that's an issue for you, but that's what it would need.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT!
I want to achieve that without MS Teams bot but seems like it's not possible right now.
For now, I've achieved this using Slack slash commands!

Thanks to all of you for your responses!